# Installing a relay to control duct fans!

Tags: hvac

I want to install a 24v/110 relay to control the two duct fans that I installed in my ducts. The idea is that the fans will come on when the blower comes on. To test this, I ran an 18/2 thermostat wire, and connected the red wire to the G thermostat terminal(green terminal) in the furnace and the white wire to the C/Common terminal(blue terminal)in the furnace. On the other side of the relay(the load side) I connected a box fan. The problem I’m having is that the box fan runs when the igniter turns on and turns off when the igniter turns off. It does not stay on with the blower being on to cool the furnace and to push the hot air out to the vents. Any suggestions? Thanks!!
PS: The box fan seems to stay on in the fan-only and AC mode, but not in heat mode.[image][image]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: Is exchanging the relay for a different relay an option?

Comment: This is the second relay I used and it is doing the same thing the first one did. I uploaded the wiring diagram like you asked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

### Your G terminal isn't meant for that

On gas furnaces, the G terminal is basically an "override" input to allow the end user to turn the fan on without a call for heat or cooling.  As a result, your results with your current fan relay aren't totally surprising; in fact, it shouldn't turn on at all unless you set the fan switch on your thermostat to ON.

### But, your goal is still achievable

However, you can still get where you want to go.  You'll simply need a different relay with a 120VAC capable coil (a RIBU1C mounted to a junction box will work just fine for this) instead of your current, 24VAC-coiled fan relay.  The coil of said relay connects to the EAC-H and EAC-N terminals on your furnace's control board using crimp-on female quick-disconnect terminals, and the contacts switch the fan on and off just like you are doing with your existing relay.  Note that you'll need to use mains-rated wiring methods for the connection from the furnace to this relay; a piece of 14-2 AC or MC that uses stranded wire is your best bet, or you can use 3 14AWG THHNs (or 2, in a metal conduit) in your choice of conduit flavors if that's your preference.

Comment: Great thanks for your suggestion!! Where are those terminals located on the furnace? A wiring diagram for all this would be really helpful and much appreciated ( from furnace to relay and from relay to fan)

Comment: @user132109 -- they're on the control board, and the wiring's pretty trivial, you just need to make sure you use the correct coil connections on the relay for a 120V input

Comment: Thanks!! I’ll keep you posted when I hook them up. Thank you again!!

Comment: It worked!! The duct fan, though, turns on as soon as the ignitor turns on and stays on throughout the blower cycle then turns off. Is it supposed to turn on when the ignitor turns on?

Comment: @user132109 -- that depends on how your control board handles the EAC terminals -- I don't think it's a terribly big deal as long as it cycles alongside the furnace blower

Comment: Great!! I do appreciate your help a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user132109 -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)